# Combine values from multiple rows into one row with each value in it's own column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of sites were customers can register and I want to combine in one row all the customer IDs associated with an email address across all sites. I am working in SQL Sever.

Example source data:

[image]

What I would like to achieve in a new table:

[image]

My first thought was something like this, with email as primary key but it doesn't work. Could I use a CASE expression?

```
SELECT c.[Email],
       (SELECT c.[CustomerID] FROM Customer c WHERE c.[BrandID] = '1859') AS [Brand1],
       (SELECT c.[CustomerID] FROM Customer c WHERE c.[BrandID] = '1594') AS [Brand2],
       (SELECT c.[CustomerID] FROM Customer c WHERE c.[BrandID] = '4578') AS [Brand3]
  FROM Customer c
```

Comment: please share texts instead of pictures to show data. somebody like me cannot see the images due to existence of some filterings.And the texts are easily copied to be used within the fiddles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.Email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BrandID = 1859 THEN c.[CustomerID] END) as Brand1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BrandID = 1594 THEN c.[CustomerID] END) as Brand2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN BrandID = 4578 THEN c.[CustomerID] END) as Brand3
FROM Customer c
GROUP BY c.Email;
```

`BrandID` looks like a number so I removed the single quotes around the comparison value.  Of course, use single quotes if it is really a string.

Comment: OP doesn't need sum but customerId.

Comment: @Gordon you need to add BrandID and customerID column in group by if you remove SUM, you query doesnot return the expected output

Comment: @RedDevil, I had edited this answer and forgot to include MAX function.

Comment: @Gordon how about if the data is not int but a date instead? thanks

Comment: @codeseeker . . . It would be exactly the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try case like this:

```
SELECT c.Email,
   SUM(CASE WHEN BrandID = 1859 THEN CustomerID ELSE 0 END) as Brand1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN BrandID = 1594 THEN CustomerID ELSE 0 END) as Brand2,
   SUM(CASE WHEN BrandID = 4578 THEN CustomerID ELSE 0 END) as Brand3
FROM Customer c
GROUP BY c.Email;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use sum?

Comment: Yes in order to have all the output in a single row we need to use SUM

Comment: Don't you think case alone will handle that.

Comment: No, If we just use case statement it will return 3 separate rows, We have to use an aggregate function to achieve the desired output

Comment: Agreed, and we can replace the SUM with MAX.

Comment: Yes we can replace with max as well

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pivot` for same.

```
 ; with cte as (
 select row_number() over (partition by email order by brandid) as Slno,
 Email, brandid from table)
  , ct as (
  select brandid, 'brand' + cast(slno as varchar(5)) as Col, email from cte )
  select * from (
  select brandid, col, email from ct ) as d
  pivot (
  max(brandid) for col in ( [brand1], [brand2], [brand3] )
  ) as p
```